# ComboBox repeat the same value in DisplayMember and ValueMember

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi i am trying to fill a combo box but the value member is the same as the displaymember
this is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                refresh();

            }

            public void refresh()
            {
                using (var context = new AppDbContext())
                {
                    var piece = context.piece.Select(d => d.quantity);
                    comboBox1.DataSource = piece.ToList();
                    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "quantity";
                    comboBox1.ValueMember = "quantity";



                }

            }
```

I receive this error message: system.argumentexception 'cannot bind to the new display member. parameter name newdisplaymember'

having only the DisplayMember and the valuemember as = "" I don't get any problem, but I need to show and save the same data, what is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to not set ValueMember? Maybe if you don't set that, the value will be the same as the display one.

Comment: Thank you very much I had no idea that leaving it empty took the other default value